# Voting on Tag synonyms

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms, events

I know that there is a feature request pending to make this a review task.  But in the mean time can we get an event or something to go through the pending synonyms and do general tag cleanup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, only moderators can do this at the moment AND Stack Exchange doesn't flag up pending tag synonym requests. I for instance happen to stumble upon outstanding requests when going through the tag synonym list during other cleanup tasks. If something has been pending for a while, just ping the diamonds on chat and one of us will process the outstanding queue.

Comment: Not really.  Regular users can vote on synonyms if they have sufficient reputation within the tag.  I was able to vote on the synonyms submitted by @hippietrail